# Cross-database trigger in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, triggers

I have two tables `CrossDBTrigTest_1` and `CrossDBTrigTest_2` on same SQL Server instance.

The databases both have a table called `Employee`.

I wrote the following trigger on the `Employee` table `CrossDBTrigTest_1 db`:

```
Create Trigger [dbo].[CrossDBInsert] on [dbo].[employee] after insert
AS 
Begin
  Set nocount on

  Insert into CrossDBTrigTest_2.employee(FirstName, LastName, Date) 
    SELECT inserted.FirstName, inserted.LastName, getdate() 
    FROM inserted
End
```

but the `Insert` statement fails with message:

> Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Procedure CrossDBInsert, Line 5
>   Invalid object name 'CrossDBTrigTest_2.employee'.

How do I enable cross database triggers in situations like this??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

```
CrossDBTrigTest_2..employee
```

as table name. Note two dots instead of one.

Answer (score 8):

Shouldn't

```
  CrossDBTrigTest_2.employee(FirstName,LastName,Date)
```

be

```
  CrossDBTrigTest_2.dbo.employee(FirstName,LastName,Date)
```

???